# UnityWebRequest Post Getting unknown response

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am sending post request by unity to local server and i set content Type of this post but the post request is not printable its showing something strange. if i use without content type then i can print request but i need this with content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`

```
     formData.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("ig_sig_key_version=4&signed_body=62aebf432dabdb788be8f2d5449ca09514e4fb78591553ee88af22ac8b6a14ea.%7B%22device_id%22%3A%22android-d693d554e0ede0d75f7d2873b015f2286%22%2C%22guid%22%3A%2283d87ba58b994d1998be5df330377d66%22%2C%22username%22%3A%xxxxxx%40gmail.com%22%2C%22password%22%3A%22xxxxx%22%2C%22Content-Type%22%3A%22application%2Fx-www-form-urlencoded%3B+charset%3DUTF-8%22%7D"));


    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://localhost/log/test.php", formData);

    www.chunkedTransfer = false;
    www.uploadHandler.contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";

    yield return www.SendWebRequest();
    Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
```

I am getting this output it cannot printable

```
  Array
   (
    [

   --GqHBbNKAAQ8E8nknl4DYZQmzN3aDDDccDL5DqfSM // This must not be part or request

   Content-Disposition:_form-data

   Content-Type:_text/plain;_encoding] => utf-8
  // This must not be part or request


    ig_sig_key_version=4
    [signed_body] => 62aebf432dabdb788be8f2d5449ca09514e4fb78591553ee88af22ac8b6a14ea.{"device_id":"android-d693d554e0ede0d75f7d2873b015f2286","guid":"83d87ba58b994d1998be5df330377d66","username":"xxxxxx@gmail.com","password":"xxxxxx","Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}

  --GqHBbNKAAQ8E8nknl4DYZQmzN3aDDDccDL5DqfSM-- // This must not be part or request


 )
```

PHP SIDE

```
 <?php
  print_r($_POST);
```

I need this response

```
   [ig_sig_key_version] => 4
   [signed_body] => f722ea0761e497c7ff27eae5c583ff47ad074a5ff92e27e01ea23859006b4df6.{"device_id":"android-298f587406c914fad5373bb6893004332","guid":"6a1136d6b70b4f7ea57cfa5a3a707c5a","username":"xxxxxxx@gmail.com","password":"xxxxxxx","Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}
  )
```

Comment: You send MultipartFormData, but set ContentType to x-www-form-urlencoded, so which format do you want?

Comment: @shingo I updated equation My problem is i set 2 parameter in my post data but only 1 is accessible

Comment: I mean MultipartFormData and x-www-form-urlencoded are different format, you cant mix them.